# Titanium mobile, android close WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, titanium-mobile

I am wondering if it is possible to kill, close the created webview after it is not needed. It has like 4mb memory leak and I just cant find a way to kill it.

For example:

```
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
  html:'hello world'
});

var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

win.addEventListener('android:back', function(e){
  win.remove(webview);  
  win.close();
});
```

But it does not work. I still see no change in memory use. Anyone maybe knows the solution?

Comment: The garbage collector will only run when there is memory pressure... this may actually be released, and just not collected.  It should be a candidate when the variable goes out of scope, but if you want an object released sooner you may set the reference to null as Ben suggests.

Comment: You can force a gc by accessing the java runtime directly.  This is for Android only, so if you go multi-platform you need to deal with that.  Something like java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); should work.  You can also get better memory stats from the runtime than you can from Ti.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you delete the reference to the webview, such as `delete webview`, Javascript's garbage collector should pick it up eventually and free up the memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the reference to null, the GC will collect it when it runs.